# Does Cholesterol Measurement vary throughout the day?

Tags: time-of-day, cholesterol, ldl, hdl

If cholesterol is mostly produced at night, is there any evidence on whether or not cholesterol tests  (TC, LDL, HDL, etc) done early in the morning produce different results compared to doing them later in the day?